# MS Teams, Power Automate and ChatGTP API

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, openai-api

I have created a MS flow, which is trigger from a MS Teams channel where the phase 'chatgpt' is mentioned.  In my flow it takes the details from the Teams message and then send them to the Chatgpt API, the flow then responses to the oringal message with the details from chatgpt.

The issue is that the reply is triggering the flow when it replies and thus creating an infinate loop.  It only stopped when the flow is turned off

I have added this function 'replace(body('HTTP')['choices'][0]?['text'], 'chatGPT', '')' to remove all mentions i chatgpt in the reply, but it still loops over.  [image: details of http requets to flow]
[image: whole flow]

Comment: could you please check if text being sent in channel has chat-gpt mentioned. Also, another check you could add to verify if current trigger is for first message or not by checking if MessageId == ReplyToMessageId. Please let me know if this helps.